# Why belongsTo() return null?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models and two tables. First model name `Inbox` with database structure:

[image]

And second model name is `StudentData` with database structure:

[image]

And I will return with `route('/sended')` all mesages using my method for get needed messages:

```
public function getMessages($message_type = "new")
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $inbox = new Inbox();

    $paginate = 3;

    switch ($message_type) {

        case 'sended':
            $messages = $inbox->where('sender', $user_id)
                              ->where('trashed_in_sender', 0)
                              ->where('show_in_sender', 0)
                              ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                              ->paginate($paginate);
            break;
        default:
            return abort(404);
            break;
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

And I have methods in my model `Inbox`:

```
public function messageSender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\StudentData", 'sender');
}

public function messageRecipient()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\StudentData", 'recipient');
}
```

When I call in view `$message->messageSender` in result given NULL. Why I can't get data using `sender id` from `inboxes` table in `student_datas` table

Comment: what is id_user field in studentData table ?

Comment: I remember back then that we always had problems when the datatypes are not the same. Your id in StudentData is int(10) and the sender and recipient are int(11) and tinyint(4) respectively... could that be it?

Comment: Is Inbox in this context a model? `$inbox = new Inbox();`

Comment: id_user is user id's from users table. In users table not saved user names. In users tables have only users id and users email. All users names and more info in student_datas table

Comment: Yes @Casper Spruit

Comment: So it should not be by the rule? @Inuyaki

Comment: ? I said your database table fields are most likely not correct. "sender" and "recipient" both have to be int(10) also, I think. Like the corresponding id field in StudentData.
Another possible problem, die you setup the StudentData model correctly? Do you get stuff by using StudentData::first()? I will write an answer below, because I have some more questions and remarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have a few questions....

1) How exactly does your User and StudentData models interact? It kinda seems strange to have 2 models with what seems to be a 1:1 relationship?
Why not just use a User model?
(Do you even have a User model or am I misinterpreting things?)

2) I think your direction is wrong... if you already have a User model, try to get the sent messages from there. I will give you an example.

Let's say you have a User model and a Inbox model, where you have a "sender" and "recipient", which both have an id of the User model.
So in the Inbox model we have:

```
public function messageSender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'sender');
}

public function messageRecipient()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'recipient');
}
```

But why not go from the other direction? We can write the relationships in the User model like

```
public function sentMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Inbox", 'sender');
}
public function receivedMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Inbox", 'recipient');
}
```

Now you can get all sent messages (i.e. all messages where the user is the sender) just by using

```
$user->sentMessages
```

and operate on that. Or you could even set up a special helper relation (my name sucks, find a better one... just for example)

```
public function unreadSentMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Inbox", 'sender')
                ->where('trashed_in_sender', 0)
                ->where('show_in_sender', 0)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

and can either use $user->sentMessages for all his messages or $user->unreadSentMessages for only the ones you need in your case.

Comment: You are right! He has to change the relations. I was confused by his where clause, but, my fault! Regards

Comment: Ok then I will change relations! Thanks for all an for @Inuyaki